python script doesn't run correctly when run by a crontab
I have a python script that runs properly when i execute it manually, but not when i use a crontab.
The script recuperate information from a file and store them in a database.
When the script is run by the crontab, i don't get all the rows in the database (i get some of them).
I am using /usr/local/bin/python which my terminal use too (i checked using which python)
Here is my crontab:
RUN (crontab -u www-data -l; echo "00 07 * * 2-5 /usr/local/bin/python /full_path/script.py >> /full_path/file.txt") | crontab -u www-data -
I want to understand why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Are you running this in the system crontab, or in your user crontab?

You can be more specific about your environment. If you are using the RUN command, are you preparing a Docker? Give more context, please.

My guess is you're probably not starting the crontab daemon when your container runs. Does this answer your question? How to run a cron job inside a docker container?

To answer @sytech i have other crontab jobs that are running successfully.

to answer @TimRoberts and André, i am setting up the cron jobs within a Dockerfile for containerized deployment. They are configured within a Docker environment

I am confused about this affirmation. "When the script is run by the crontab, i don't get all the rows in the database (i get some of them)." So, your script runs, but the result is different from what you expected?

@AndréCarvalho Yes, exactly. For example, the file containing the information has around 50 rows, but when I check the database after running the cron job, I find fewer rows, and the number varies each time. However, when I execute the script manually, all 50 rows are successfully inserted into the database.

No one can help you without reproducing the problem and they lack details to do so. Try to track the issue by including the output log that records the execution steps and use the transaction to keep your bank consistent.
